# Como por comentários na função definida pelo usuário no Excel/VB

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções, visual-basic-6

Eu gostaria de saber como por aquela ajuda nas funções definidas pelo usuário no Excel. 
**Não é como cria a função definida pelo usuário**, e *sim como adiciona instruções como o usuário* deve manipula-la.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da uma olhada, nessa pergunta no SOEN: [The quest for the Excel custom function tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903587/the-quest-for-the-excel-custom-function-tooltip/17517538#17517538), fala sobre ExcelDNA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para incluir esta descrição sem usar o ExcelDNA, utilizei as propriedades da função (Acessada pelo Pesquisador de Objetos F2). Veja abaixo:

[image: Resultado final]
[image: Pesquisador de Objeto]
[image: Janela de Descrição]

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo meu! Ajudou bastante já!